# Replace DesktopScope.put() and DesktopScope.put() in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, zk

There are my project that are use 2 methods of the zk framework

DesktopScope.put() and DesktopScope.put()

and now i am removing zk. there are from wchi methods i can replace this method in servlet file

```
desktopScope.put("USER_NAME", userNameVal);
desktopScope.put(Constants.USER_DIR, userDirectory);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page in the ZK documentation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML%20Reference/EL%20Expressions/Implicit%20Objects%20%28Predefined%20Variables%29/desktopScope), the `desktopScope` object is a `Map` maintained by the ZK framework that holds variables shared at a particular scoping level; i.e. the desktop level.

Now I can't figure out what the "wchi" framework is ... or whether that is just a typo.  But if you are simply converting your code to plain JSP / JSTL code, then you need to figure out an appropriate JSP / JSTL scope (the standard ones are "page", "session", "request" and "application") and then set your variable from Java, depending on the scope:

- "request" scope variables are set using `Request.setAttribute`
- "session" scope variables are set using `Session.setAttribute`
- "application" scope variables are setting `ServletContext.setAttribute`
- "page" scope variables cannot be set outside of the page JSP.

Note that the "desktop" scope is a purely ZK concept, and you are going to need to figure out a non-ZK way of achieving .... whatever it is that those variables achieve.  The "session" scope might be the most appropriate.